# Extracting text from SMS message in Python

Tags: python, sms

This is an SMS message which I obtained using AT commands from mobile:

```
+CMGL: 24,"REC READ","DD-655501",,"11/11/10,17:10:26+22"
hey is it working "BBC news channel" pack @ Rs.10, Dial *234*7514#
```

Now I need to extract **only** the text message from it. I have tried a few approaches but something always gets missed. I am using Python. Any good suggestion?

Comment: Which part is the SMS message?

Comment: You might want to look into gammu, a library for communicating with mobiles. It has Python bindings. http://wammu.eu/gammu/

Answer (score 1):

The format of the response is:

```
+CMGL: index,message_status,address,[address_text],[service_center_time_stamp][,address_type,sms_message_body_length]
sms_message_body
```

([source](http://www.developershome.com/sms/cmglCommand.asp))

You want all the text apart from the first line.

```
message_body = smsText[smsText.index('\r\n') + 2:]
```

Comment: It is not working.                                                               >>> smstext="""hey is it working "BBC news channel" pack @ Rs.10, Dial *234*7514#"""
>>> message_body = smstext[smstext.index('\r\n') + 2:]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    message_body = smstext[smstext.index('\r\n') + 2:]
ValueError: substring not found
>>>

Comment: @user1043500: That's because you forgot the first line.

Comment: I am making some mistake but I am unable to figure that out.

Comment: This is what I am getting by including the first line              >>> s="""+CMGL: 24,"REC READ","DD-655501",,"11/11/10,17:10:26+22"
hey is it working "BBC news channel" pack @ Rs.10, Dial *234*7514#"""
>>> message_body = s[s.index('\r\n') + 2:]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    message_body = s[s.index('\r\n') + 2:]
ValueError: substring not found
>>>

Comment: @user1043500: Probably you have `\n` instead of `\r\n` in your input string.